# How to use the LDSwiftEventSource library correctly

Tags: swift, server-sent-events, watchos, launchdarkly

I was looking for Server-Sent events on watchos and found https://github.com/launchdarkly/swift-eventsource this library. The only problem is that there is no documentation on how to use it correctly. Is anyone familiar with it. Let me know please.

Comment: When you have a question about a specific open source library that's not that widely used, you might have a better chance at getting an answer directly from the developers of the library by raising an issue on the GitHub page of the library.

Comment: I created simple package using Swift Concurrency, if you want to, check it out https://github.com/RobertDresler/SwiftSSEStream

Answer (score 1):

you can look at there mock implementation in their sdk

[github](https://github.com/launchdarkly/ios-client-sdk/blob/v8/LaunchDarkly/LaunchDarklyTests/Mocks/LDEventSourceMock.swift)